# How can I generate list via v-for in Vue

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am trying to generate list of some defined variables using `v-for`.

I have list of some Strings... `["Electronics","Furniture", "Cloths", "Sports", "Entertainment", "Others"]` and in each tag `<li>` I want to generate some `<img>` and `<a>` tag with custom text.

So I would imagine list with all the things above but nothing shows up. How can I change my code to generate list of these items?

Code in **App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app h-100">

    <Header></Header>

    <div class="center-page h-100">
      <Navigation></Navigation>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Header from "@/components/TheHeader";
  import Navigation from "@/components/TheNavigation";

  export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {
      Navigation,
      Header
    }

  }
</script>
```

This is **hierarchy** of my project. This code is in **`TheHeader`**.
[image: Hierarchy]

```
<ul id="example" class="menu-dropdown">
   <li v-for="item in items" :key="item" class="center align-self-center">
      <img class="float-left" href="@/assets/logo.png" src="@/assets/logo.png"  />
       <a href="#"><h3>{{item}}</h3></a>
   </li>
</ul>


<script>
    import Vue from "vue";

    new Vue({
        el: '#example',
        data:{
            items:["Electronics","Furniture", "Cloths", "Sports", "Entertainment", "Others"]
        }
    })

    export default {
        name: 'Header',
        props:{},
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to keep one vue instance in one component.
Also don't forget about `<template>` tag.

```html
<template>
    <ul id="example" class="menu-dropdown">
        <li v-for="item in items" :key="item" class="center align-self-center">
            <img class="float-left"/>
            <a href="#"><h3>{{item}}</h3></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>


<script>
    export default {
        name: 'TheHeader',
        props: {},
        data() {
            return {
                items: ["Electronics", "Furniture", "Cloths", "Sports", "Entertainment", "Others"]
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

add key correctly in for

> v-for="item in items" :key="item.index"

Comment: This solution is not working for me... still throws an error I think that it's because of new Vue instance as mentioned @Evgeniy Kuznetsov